# ¿Cómo acceder al contenido de un archivo .html con Vue.js?

Tags: html, vue.js, archivo

Estoy intentando acceder al contenido de un fichero con extensión .html desde Vue.js.

Para hacerlo más visual, el contenido del archivo mi-tabla.html es:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Y mediante Vue.js quiero acceder a ese archivo para poder recorrerlo y realizar una búsqueda. Por ejemplo extraer la información de la fila que contenga Alemania (country=Germany).

En primer lugar ¿es posible?. Si es así ¿cómo puedo obtener el contenido de mi-tabla.html?.
Y en segundo lugar, una vez accedo al contenido ¿cuál sería la mejor manera de recorrerlo para realizar búsquedas sobre él y extraer la fila deseada?

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia en si, pues la solución base es con el lenguaje JS

Answer (score -1):

En el html justo antes del cierre de la etiqueta body pones lo siguiente:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="Vue.js"></script>
```

Para poder acceder a la informacion, esto es un pequeño ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Ejemplo de como guardar en una variable el contenido de una celda
    //En este caso seria Germany
    //El :eq() empieza a contar desde 0
    var country = $('table > tr:eq(1) > td:eq(2)').text();
    //Mostrar contenido de la variable con alert();
    alert(country);
});
```

Deberías consultar como acceder al DOM con jquery y manipular la información

Comment: No veo para que JQuery si el OP lo que usa es VueJS y es con este con el que trata de acceder a los elementos

Comment: @BetaM Cuando en la pregunta Geline hizo mencion a Vue.js entendi que se trataba de un archivo javascript o jquery ya que estos tienen la extension .js. El motivo por el que puse un pequeño ejemplo con jquery es por que es mas sencillo que hacerlo con javascript

Comment: @BetaM por como tiene puesta la pregunta entendí que tenia un archivo con el nombre Vue.js. Acabo de enterarme de que se trata de un framework.

Comment: @Geline disculpame, malentendí tu pregunta, espero que des con la solución.